Copy Content with Images to Other Site
Wondering if anyone has come up with any creative workarounds for copying content which includes images from one site to another? I looked into it many years ago and didn't get far, but wondering if anything new or insightful these days?
We typically keep development copies of websites for testing updates, bug fixing, showing new content to clients for approval, etc. And I know we can do a 'Copy All Blocks' on a page/post, then paste into the live site when ready to port over. But this won't bring any images over, it will just point back to the image sources on the Dev site.
Any way other than manually re-uploading and re-placing all images on the live site when copying the content over? We've sucked it up and done this up to now on a few projects, but current project has a lot of posts, each with a lot of images, and each with unique captions. This can't be that uncommon of a task, is it?!?
